# Anchor scroll is scrolling to the anchor upon page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any help with this is greatly appreciated! I have a button at the top of my product page for a sizing chart which anchor scrolls to the sizing chart image at the bottom of the page. However, upon page load, the page automatically scrolls down to the sizing chart. What can I modify so that the page does not automatically scroll down to the anchor? Here is my JS:

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that the page scrolls down when it is reloaded.

It is default browsers behaviour to scroll the page down to the point the user were the last time she/he visited the page.

To avoid that scroll to top **before the page is closed**:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue. What's happening is, when you load the page, the page automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page upon load. This breezes past the product description and takes you right to the bottom of the page. I am needing the page to load normally so a user doesn't end up at the bottom of each page that contains a sizing chart. Hopefully that adds a little clarity to the issue that I am experiencing!